# Passing the time

Tags: connect-wall

Here in the United States, COVID is now casting a long shadow over our summer. To help pass the time where we should be enjoying our normal summer activities, here's a connect wall to remind us of what we could be doing. The set of sixteen words below can be partitioned into groups of four words that have something in common. And of course the commonalities have something in common, which is related to the title of the puzzle. I wish you luck!

ALL, BOARD, BOTTLE, COLD, DEALER, DEGREE, HAPPY, INNING, MODULAR, OLDEST, PINES, SOLO, TEAR, TENDER, THESIS, WHITE

HINT:

> Two of the groups are based on fitting in a phrase with the connecting word. One of the groups is based on wordplay with the connecting word, and the other is a group whose members fall in a category described by the connecting word.

HINT:

> DEALER and OLDEST are in the same group, which is not based on wordplay.

HINT:

> ALL and PINES are in the same group, which is not based on fitting in a phrase with a connecting word.

HINT: This turned out harder than I thought it would be...sorry about that! @hexomino has gotten the groups mostly correct, but to get things over the finish line:

Group 1:

> Wordplay based (think insertion): contains ALL, INNING, PINES

Group 2:

> Phrase based: contains BOARD, COLD, TENDER

Group 3:

> Phrase based (consider plurals): contains DEGREE, TEAR, THESIS

Group 4:

> Examples of something (think games, but one is a bit of an Easter egg): contains DEALER, OLDEST, SOLO

Comment: I think I've managed to successfully identify one category since yesterday. This certainly is a tough one, nice work.

Comment: Thanks @hexomino! I'm glad it worked out the way it did...I can provide another hint tomorrow if needed.

Comment: In the first hint, do you mean the rot13(pbaarpgvat jbeq sbe gur svany nafjre, be sbe rnpu vaqvivqhny tebhc)?

Comment: @tmpearce: In the first hint, the "connecting word" is the word describing each group. No hint is offered on how to get from the four "connecting words" to the final answer. Does that clarify?

Comment: @JeremyDover Yes, that helps - the hint refers to multiple connecting words, one for each group, not the ultimate connecting word.

Comment: @JeremyDover I have edited my answer which I think is a lot closer now to what you were looking for but I'm still not 100% on the final connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**New Answer**

Group 1

> Words which can have the word **TO** inserted into them to form a new word - ALL, INNING, MODULAR, PINES (A**TO**LL, IN**TO**NING, MODULA**TO**R, PIN**TO**ES)

Group 2

> Words that form a new word/phrase with the word **FEET** - BOARD, COLD, [TENDER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/tenderfeet), HAPPY

Group 3

> These are all phrases when combined with numbers in the **NINETIES** - (98) DEGREE(s), (96) TEAR(s), (95) THES(e)S, (99) BOTTLE(s)

Group 4

> These are things which come **FIRST** - OLDEST, DEALER (cards), WHITE (chess), [SOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_shot_first)

Connections

> Combining them in a certain way we have NINETY FEET TO FIRST which is a reference to **BASEBALL** as that's how far apart the bases are (thanks to Jeremy Dover for the correction, I originally had it slightly wrong).
>  Baseball is referred to as **America's Pastime** which is the link to the title (thanks to El-Guest for pointing this out).

**Previous answer**

> **Group 1**
>  Words to which we can add **S** to the front to create a new word - ALL, COLD, INNING, PINES.
>  Here I think the "connecting word" is SAND because each new word formation is **S AND** word.
>  **Group 2**
>  Words which create a phrase when combined with **WATER** - BOARD, BOTTLE, TENDER, WHITE
>  **Group 3**
>  Words which create a phrase when combined with **PAPER** - DEGREE, [MODULAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_origami), TEAR, THESIS
>  **Group 4**
>  Words which are associated with the **WHEEL** - (wheeler) DEALER, [HAPPY (wheels)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Wheels), OLDEST (not totally sure but could be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljubljana_Marshes_Wheel)), [SOLO(wheel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_unicycle#Companies).
>  So the connecting words are
>  SAND, WATER, PAPER, WHEEL
>  Which makes me think that the commonality is
>  FLY - SAND**FLY**, WATER-**FLY**, **FLY**PAPER, **FLY**WHEEL

Comment: I really like your solution, but it's pretty far off what I had in mind (and mine is less stretchy, I think). As a hint, rot13(Ebgngr PBYQ, OBGGYR naq ZBQHYNE). That will get two of my groups, and you'll be a single transposition away from the other two.

Comment: Your four categories are exactly the same as I've got this afternoon, and likewise I'm feeling stumped by the final connection! I'm thinking if you use rot13(SVEFG CREFBA) this might lead to something in the way of gaming...

Comment: @Stiv Maybe you can see something more than I can. I can see how your phrase relates to gaming but not the other groups. Although, admittedly, it's not something I know a lot about.

Comment: And of course you have that your answer is rot13(_Nzrevpn’f Cnfgvzr_), @hexomino

Comment: @El-Guest Ah, yes, that is true. I might edit that in with credit.

Comment: That's it! In my mind the phrase cluing the final answer was rot13(avargl srrg gb svefg), but you got the correct final answer. One quick question: rot13(sbe juvpu tnzr qbrf FBYB tb svefg?)

Comment: @JeremyDover At first, I though this was a reference to a one-player game but with your clarification I'm now thinking it's a reference to rot13("Una fubg svefg"). Is that right?

Comment: Absolutely! I'm old enough to have seen the original in theaters, so I know the truth :-)

Comment: Great puzzle, by the way. Looking back my previous groups 3 and 4 were very dodgy but I got so caught up in the ideas for 1 and 2 that I thought the rest must fit somehow. The connections here are really well done.

Comment: Seeing the rest of these comments now it looks like you were spot on with your conclusion even when you weren't confident about it - well done :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I started with the rot13(avargl) category first, and the rest just fell in place. Hope you enjoyed!